# How to increase the speed to load an activity?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity

I am developing an Android application and it uses  GoogleMaps. So when I click on a Button, I load a registraPosizioneActivity that shows the google maps. So I have noted that the loading speed of this activity is slow. Is there a mode for increasing the speed of loading this activity?

This is my code:

```
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            try{
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_recordposition);
                locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0, this);
                settaMappa();
                if(myPosition==null){
                    pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Attendere ...", "Localizzazione in corso ...", true);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("Errore onCreate:",e.getMessage());
                Utility.generateNoteOnSD(fileName,e.getMessage());
            }
        }

       public void settaMappa(){
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map2)).getMap();
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
```

This is activity_recordposition.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".registraPosizioneActivity"
    android:gravity="center">


    <fragment 
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      android:id="@+id/map2"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="10"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonR"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="#0080c2"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:onClick="registraPunto"
        android:text="@string/registraPunto" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSava"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="#0080c2"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:onClick="savaAreaTracciata"
        android:text="@string/terminaRegistrazione" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you actually checked how long the activity takes for the main life cycle methods?

Comment: I have comment all code on onCreate method, but the speed to load my activity is low.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like you're doing a lot of processing in the onCreate method. Try moving some of this processing into an Async thread. I believe that will increase load times by a lot.

So,

- Load up the activity, within the onCreate start an Async task
- Async thread does the processing required after the activity has
  loaded :)

Comment: there is nothing that really looks he is doing a lot, just setting up a location manager and getting the map. thats nothing

Comment: Hiya,
It may not be much but he's set the accuracy to fine to clearly the device he's testing it from is taking a while to get the GPS coordinates and thus the activity doesn't seem to load very fast. If he runs the activity and does the GPS processing in another thread (Async). The activity will be appear almost instantaneously and the Async thread run in the background :). It's not gotten any faster, but, the activity is loading faster, which is what he wanted.

Comment: getting a GPS lock has nothing to do with the speed of loading an activity. an activity can load without ever getting a GPS lock

Comment: Ok sorry, I thought because the GPS lock was in the onCreate method, the activity wasn't loading until the GPS lock was successful. Oops :)

Comment: Shall I delete my answer?

Comment: I have comment all code on onCreate method, but the speed to load my activity is low.